# Printing pattern using Jagged Array

Tags: java

Given the jagged Array, we are asked to use a looping statement to display the character based on the position. Display a "*" if the position matched or a " " if it doesn't.

```
        int arr [][] = {{0,4,8,12,13,14,15,18,19,20,21,24,28},
       {0,4,7,9,12,16,18,22,25,27},
       {0,1,2,3,4,6,10,12,16,18,22,26},
       {0,4,6,10,12,13,14,15,18,19,20,21,26},
       {0,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,18,26},
       {0,4,6,10,12,18,26}};
```

I have created a program, but the output is not what I expected and I am now stuck.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length - 1; j++)
          {
              for (int spaces = 1; spaces < arr[i][j + 1]-arr[i][j]; spaces++)
              {
               System.out.print(" ");
              }
              System.out.print("*");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
```

The output was suppose to be Happy but I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dcIl.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your program does not compare the first `j` value (which is 0) with itself. Since every value equals itself you can add manually `*` for each line like this.

```
int arr [][] = {{0,4,8,12,13,14,15,18,19,20,21,24,28},
               {0,4,7,9,12,16,18,22,25,27},
               {0,1,2,3,4,6,10,12,16,18,22,26},
               {0,4,6,10,12,13,14,15,18,19,20,21,26},
               {0,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,18,26},
               {0,4,6,10,12,18,26}};
     
     
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     {
         System.out.print("*");
         
         for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length - 1; j++)
         {
             for (int spaces = 1; spaces < arr[i][j + 1]-arr[i][j]; spaces++)
             {
              System.out.print(" ");
             }
             System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, p = -1; j < arr[i].length; p = arr[i][j++])
            System.out.print(" ".repeat(arr[i][j] - p - 1) + "*");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

output:

```
*   *   *   ****  ****  *   *
*   *  * *  *   * *   *  * *
***** *   * *   * *   *   *
*   * *   * ****  ****    *
*   * ***** *     *       *
*   * *   * *     *       *
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).